# The premises of Aczel's inductive definitions

Tags: lo.logic, definitions, transfinite-induction

This is a follow-up to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650053/are-inductive-definitions-finitely-generated-in-isabelle

As I said there, Aczel writes in his paper [An Introduction to Inductive Definitions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08711200):

> a *rule* is a pair $(X,x)$, where $X$ is a set, called the set of *premisses* and $x$ is the *conclusion*. The rule will usually be written $X\rightarrow x$.

And this does not say anything about the finiteness of $X$, the premises set.

And, indeed, at section 1.2, The well-founded part of a relation, he uses

> Let $\Phi_\prec$ be the set of rules $(\prec a)\rightarrow a$ for $a\in A$, where $(\prec a) = \{x\in A | x\prec a\}$.

and, as far as I understand, the relation $\prec$ is not necessarily well-founded, so the rules might have infinite premises. And, here even the number of rules might be infinite, if the carrier set $A$ is infinite.

Now, as an answer [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49650321/1697709) for the quoted question, in the Isabelle theorem prover there are only finitely generated inductive definitions.

Are infinitely generated inductive definitions a matter of mathematical research, as in transfinite induction, or there are examples in practice, i.e. formal verification?

Comment: Just wanted to mention here as well that I updated my answer that is linked in this question. This ‘infinite number of premises’ can easily be re-stated as a single premise with a universal quantifier, and it seems to me that this is generally the case with the class of definitions Aczel describes.

Comment: Even if $\prec$ is well-founded, a rule in $\Phi_\prec$ could have infinitely many premises. Consider, for example, any well-ordering of length greater than $\omega$.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s/54334#54334) gives an excellent overview of the kinds of mathematical constructions that originally motivated these notions. Possibly useful (might be in Aczel's bibliography, but I don't have access to Aczel's paper) is [**Elementary Induction on Abstract Structures**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486466787) by Yiannis N. Moschovakis (1974; reprinted by Dover Publications in 2008).